# How to create a bean collection into an XML Java confifuration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt related to the definition of a **beans collection** into an **XML configuration**.

For example I have this XML configuration snippet:

```
<bean id="service" class="com.acme.service.TransferServiceImpl">
    <property name="customerPolicies">
        <list>
            <ref bean="privateBankingCustomerPolicy"/>
            <ref bean="retailBankingCustomerPolicy"/>
            <bean class="com.acme.DefaultCustomerPolicy"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can you help me to understand how exactly work?

On the documentation I read that it is called the **public void setCustomerPollicies(java.util.List policies)) {...}** method. I think that it depend my the fact that  have to be the collection initialized with the beans object into the list. Is it right?

My doubt is: why the object into the list are different type? (a ref to a **privateBankingCustomerPolicy** bean, a ref to a **retailBankingCustomerPolicy** bean and an inner bean having type as **com.acme.DefaultCustomerPolicy**)?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signature is like this and no generics is used then any type can be added to this list.

```
public void setCustomerPollicies(java.util.List policies)
```

If you want type restriction at runtime then you must use generics

```
public void setCustomerPollicies(java.util.List<Policy> policies)
```

Comment: Ok but in practice what happens? I am setting a list with 2 references (refereces to the privateBankingCustomerPolicy and retailBankingCustomerPolicy) anto to another reference to an inner bean (com.acme.DefaultCustomerPolicy)? TNX

Comment: In practice a java.util.List implementation is created and ur policies specified are added to that list and finally that list is set to your method.